# Sort text file using bash sort

Tags: bash

I'm trying to sort the following file by date with earliest to latest:
$NAME DIA

```
# Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
01-10-2014,169.91,169.98,167.42,167.68,11019000,167.68
29-04-2014,164.62,165.27,164.49,165.00,4581400,163.40
17-10-2013,152.11,153.59,152.05,153.48,9916600,150.26
06-09-2013,149.70,149.97,147.77,149.09,9001900,145.68
02-11-2012,132.56,132.61,130.47,130.67,5141300,125.01
01-11-2012,131.02,132.44,130.97,131.98,3807400,126.27
```

sort -t- -k3 -k2 -k1 DIA.txt gets the year right but scrambles the month and day.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show an example of what the result you got was vs what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to produce correct output

```
sort -s -t- -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1
```

**output:**

```
$ sort -s -t- -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1 dia.txt
# Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
01-11-2012,131.02,132.44,130.97,131.98,3807400,126.27
02-11-2012,132.56,132.61,130.47,130.67,5141300,125.01
06-09-2013,149.70,149.97,147.77,149.09,9001900,145.68
17-10-2013,152.11,153.59,152.05,153.48,9916600,150.26
29-04-2014,164.62,165.27,164.49,165.00,4581400,163.40
01-10-2014,169.91,169.98,167.42,167.68,11019000,167.68
```

Comment: You may want to include the sorted output showing the output produced. I'll do it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the date format first.

```
sed -r "s/(..)-(..)-(....)/\\3-\\2-\\1/" DIA.txt | sort
```

You can also change it back after sorting the lines.

```
sed -r "s/(..)-(..)-(....)/\\3-\\2-\\1/" DIA.txt | sort | sed -r "s/(....)-(..)-(..)/\\3-\\2-\\1/"
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort`'s `-k` flag only allows you to specify two columns that give the range of keys to use in the sort. Here you want to involve a third column before that. There is a special syntax to use an additional column to resolve ties (here between rows when sorting with column 3 and 2):

```
sort -t'-' -k3,2.1 d
```